# How do I connect the GUI wallet to a TLS remote node?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, remote-node

I have a Monero node running in a cloud container, configured as a public node:

```
monerod --rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0 --confirm-external-bind --restricted-rpc --non-interactive
```

I have a reverse proxy sitting in front of it that does SSL termination such that you can access the RPC at `https://example.com:443/json_rpc` and get a successful response

```
curl -X POST https://example.com:443/json_rpc  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' - '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_version"}'
```

returns

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "status": "OK",
    "untrusted": false,
    "version": 131073
  }
}
```

However, when I enter my node details (`example.com` and `443`) into the remote node and port in the GUI it doesn't successfully connect.  I'm not sure where I can see more details on the error.

Searching online suggests that using a reverse proxy is the proper way to secure the JSON-RPC from prying eyes, but I can't find any information on how to connect the GUI to such a node.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the CLI or GUI have support for SSL RPC connections. Therefore you have to proxy both server *and* client over SSL. You can setup a client stunnel proxy to point to the node that is fronted by an SSL proxy and then in the GUI, specify the remote node as `localhost` and your stunnel client port.

Comment: The reverse proxy can't see the service on localhost due to containerization.  Normally, you would be correct.

Comment: I have added that missing detail to your question. And edited the answer to reflect.